# IMAP -> Gmail - extract attachment, then delete email

Tags: php, email, gmail, imap

I am running a cronjob that connects to my Gmail account and extracts a CSV file from an email with a specific subject. The attachment is then saved on my server where it is later picked for further processing.

The issue at hand now is that the cronjob is executed every 15 minutes, resulting in a huge number of emails and naturally waste of mailbox space as the attachments add up. What I want to do is to delete the email after I have extracted the attachment, but when using `imap_delete` and `imap_expunge', the email still remains in the inbox.

Delete and expunge

```
/* delete and expunge email after attachment has been exported */
imap_delete($inbox,$email_number);
imap_expunge($inbox,$email_number);
```

Full code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(3000); 


/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'YOUR_GMAIL_USERNAME'; # e.g somebody@gmail.com
$password = 'YOUR_GMAIL_PASSWORD';


/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());


/* get all NEW emails with subject line only  */
/* UPDATED as per Max' suggestion  */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'NEW SUBJECT "Automated Report 123"');

/* if any emails found, iterate through each email */
if($emails) {

    $count = 1;

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) 
    {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);

        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        /* get mail structure */
        $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $email_number);

        $attachments = array();

        /* if any attachments found... */
        if(isset($structure->parts) && count($structure->parts)) 
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($structure->parts); $i++) 
            {
                $attachments[$i] = array(
                    'is_attachment' => false,
                    'filename' => '',
                    'name' => '',
                    'attachment' => ''
                );

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifdparameters) 
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->dparameters as $object) 
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'filename') 
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['filename'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($structure->parts[$i]->ifparameters) 
                {
                    foreach($structure->parts[$i]->parameters as $object) 
                    {
                        if(strtolower($object->attribute) == 'name') 
                        {
                            $attachments[$i]['is_attachment'] = true;
                            $attachments[$i]['name'] = $object->value;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if($attachments[$i]['is_attachment']) 
                {
                    $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $email_number, $i+1);

                    /* 3 = BASE64 encoding */
                    if($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 3) 
                    { 
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = base64_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                    /* 4 = QUOTED-PRINTABLE encoding */
                    elseif($structure->parts[$i]->encoding == 4) 
                    { 
                        $attachments[$i]['attachment'] = quoted_printable_decode($attachments[$i]['attachment']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /* iterate through each attachment and save it */
        foreach($attachments as $attachment)
        {
            if($attachment['is_attachment'] == 1)
            {
                $filename = $attachment['name'];
                if(empty($filename)) $filename = $attachment['filename'];

                if(empty($filename)) $filename = time() . ".dat";

                /* prefix the email number to the filename in case two emails
                 * have the attachment with the same file name.
                 */
                $fp = fopen("./" . $email_number . "-" . $filename, "w+");
                fwrite($fp, $attachment['attachment']);
                fclose($fp);
            }

        }

        if($count++ >= $max_emails) break;

        /* delete and expunge email after attachment has been exported */
        imap_delete($inbox,$email_number);
        imap_expunge($inbox,$email_number);
    }

} 

/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);

echo "Done";

?>
```

Comment: Two problems: You are doing two searches, the second overrides the first.  Second: do not expunge until you are done, or all your email numbers will change.  When messages are expunged, all message numbers shift down to fill the hole.

Comment: @Max thanks for that. I guess this means the search should actually be `$emails = imap_search($inbox,'NEW SUBJECT "Automated Report 123"');` then, but I am not sure how to proceed with the delete/expunge as I never used that before and dont want to end up deleting my entire inbox. Do you have any sample code I can study?

Comment: Move the imap_expunge outside the loop. I don't have any sample code; I'm not a PHP programmer, just an IMAP dude ;)

Comment: @Max sometimes that's all you need ;) I'll set up another account and then test things out, thanks a lot.